# Using layerMasks with Physic2D.Linecast() in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have a simple DirectPath bool function that is meant to return true or false based on whether there is a wall between 2 points.

```
public bool DirectPath (Vector2 start, Vector2 end) {

    RaycastHit2D hitWall = Physics2D.Linecast (start, end, 8);

    if (hitWall == null) {
        Debug.Log ("Direct path returning true");
        return true;
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("Direct path returning false");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have set the layerMask for all wall colliders in the game to "Wall" which is number 8 in my layer list. But the function is returning false every time, meaning that a wall collider is being hit every time. The "start" point is also not even inside a collider, so it can't be that it is hitting its own collider. But I am wanting to use this same function to determine line of sight from the player, so that will involve a collider.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre It is 0 based, but I tried 7 and is still returning false every time. I've tried seeing what the hitwall.collider.gameObject.name is but it then returns nothing. Is that the right way to check what it is actually hitting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
RaycastHit2D hitWall = Physics2D.Linecast (start, end, 8);
```

It should be as follows:

```
RaycastHit2D hitWall = Physics2D.Linecast (start, end, (1<<8));
```

Why? Because that argument wants a layer *mask*, ie a bit mask for the layer, not an index.

That argument doesn't want just one layer, it gives the option for casting against multiple layers as defined by order of the bits in the mask (all bits will be 0 except for the one you made 1). This allows you to combine masks, and do things like `~(1<<8)` which casts against all layers except 8.

Relevant documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html

**Edit:**

An additional problem is that RaycastHit2D is a struct type. That means it will always be not null.

You want to check `if (hitWall.collider == null) {`

See: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/691622/why-does-raycast2d-always-return-non-null.html

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting false every time.

Comment: Just to make sure: Check to see that you're not hitting yourself, check your start and end points, check the configuration for colliers (and make sure you calculated the index correctly). Finally, if you're hitting something, see what you're hitting (try printing out its `gameobject.name`)

Comment: When I do Debug.Log ("Direct path returning false " + hitWall.collider.gameObject.name) nothing prints in the console...

Comment: At the moment the line is not being cast from a collider, so there shouldn't even be any other colliders in the scene apart from walls...

Comment: Wait, nothing prints to the console? Not even the 'Direct path returning false' part?

Comment: Yes, it was printing before but adding + hitWall.collider.gameObject.name results in nothing being printed in the console.

Comment: Added new info. RayCastHit2d is a not null type.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had tried that, but apparently not, that solved my problem!